# GitLab public repositories and profiles don’t show up in Google search results

Tags: git, repository, gitlab, user-profile

There is no one's repositories/ profiles show up in Google search results.
Is there any way to show my public repos in Google search results.
PS: I have found this https://forum.gitlab.com/t/gitlab-com-free-repositories-dont-show-up-in-google-search-results/3120

Answer (score 0):

This is the [official `robot.txt`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/blob/master/public/robots.txt) used by GitLab, and /profile or /*/*/.git areindeed disallowed.

[gitlab-ce issue 24289](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/24289) is about improving the SEO of GitLab itself.

Each time a new restriction is added to that file (as in [gitlab-ce commit d71edf0](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/commit/d71edf0dedb944be62390c0e6eea5f6e6da7a328)) this is to prevent sensitive information to be leaked. But that seems to apply to public and private repos alike.